# \@ifnextchar breaks kerning when expanded

Tags: fonts, best-practices, acronyms, ligatures, kerning

I've defined a macro for an initialism (abbreviation) with periods, making sure that an end-of-sentence period is not printed twice: `\gp` prints "G.P." and `\gp.` prints "G.P." Here's an M.W.E.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter\def\gp{G.P\@ifnextchar.{}{.}}\makeatother
\begin{document}
\gp{} (bad) \par \gp. (bad) \par G.P. (O.K.)
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, this breaks the kerning between the final letter and the final period — see the attached screenshot. This is a pretty minor issue of course, but I find it kind of interesting. The lack of kerning is more pronounced with some other fonts, including Palatino (`\usepackage{mathpazo}`). Am I abusing `\@ifnextchar` or is there some other issue? (The same happens with ligatures, although I can't think of a useful application for the following: `\makeatletter\def\doublef{f\@ifnextchar f{}{f}}\makeatother` and `ff --- \doublef f --- \doublef i --- ffi`.)
[image]

Comment: Any assignment between two characters breaks kerning.

Comment: @egreg Not true in LuaTeX!

Comment: `\newcommand*\gp{\@ifnextchar.{G.P}{G.P.}}`

Comment: `\def\gp{G.P.\@ifnextchar.{\@gobble}{}}`

Comment: @egreg That's good to know, and explains a few other things I haven't gotten to work.

Comment: @Herbert Perfect! And a very good example of how to use `\@gobble` (I couldn't get it to work). I ended up doing the following: `\newcommand*{\fixdot}[1]{#1\@ifnextchar.{\@gobble}{}}`, so that `\fixdot{G.P.}` and `\fixdot{G.P.}.` both output G.P.  I'm not sure how to best add a space, as in `\fixdot{G.P.} word`, which eats the space between the two. I tried using `\xspace` as the second argument to `\@ifnextchar`, but that breaks the plural form `\fixdot{G.P.}s`. I guess `\fixdot{G.P.}{} word` (awkward?) or `\fixdot{G.P.}\ word` is the way to go.

Comment: @tanh you can load `\usepackage{ltxcmds}` and then use `\newcommand*{\fixdot}[1]{#1\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace.{\@gobble}{}}`

Comment: @clemens That works in every case I can think of. Thank you, I would never I have that command myself.

Comment: How do I mark this as solved? Do I write an answer myself and accept it, or is that frowned upon?

Comment: I can write something. Or maybe better @Herbert since the solution in the end is based on his idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\def\gp{G.P.\@ifnextchar.{\@gobble}{}}
```

`\@gobble` is defined in the latex kernel as `\def\@gobble#1{}`

Comment: Thank you! Reading the definition of `\@gobble` also makes it clear wow it works. This can be generalized to take an argument using `\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace` from the ltxcmds package, as suggested by @clemens in their comment to my question.

Comment: not relevant here but `\@gobble` is declared as `\long\def\@gobble#1{}`, thus with LaTeX syntax as `\newcommand{\@gobble}[1]{}`.

Comment: yes, because `#1` can include paragraphs